# Is it possible to copy wchar_t* strings to vector as a new string of characters?

Tags: c++, winapi, wchar-t

What I am trying to do is to save multiple different pointers to unique `wchar_t` strings into a vector. My current code is this:

```
std::vector<wchar_t*> vectorOfStrings;
wchar_t* bufferForStrings;

for (i = 0, i > some_source.length; i++) {
    // copy some string to the buffer...

    vectorOfStrings.push_back(bufferForStrings);
}
```

This results in `bufferForStrings` being added to the vector again and again, which is not what I want.

```
RESULT:

[0]: (pointer to buffer)
[1]: (pointer to buffer)
...
```

What I want is this:

```
[0]: (pointer to unique string)
[1]: (pointer to other unique string)
...
```

From what I know about this type of string, the pointer points to the beginning of an array of characters which ends in a null terminator.

So, the current code effectively results in the same string being copied to the buffer again and again. How do I fix this?

Comment: `std::vector<wchar_t>` is not a "vector of strings", it's a vector of `wchar_t`s. Perhaps you are looking for `std::vector<wchar_t *>`?

Comment: `vectorOfStrings.push_back(bufferForStrings);` should fail to compile due to type mismatch `wchar_t *` vs `wchar_t`)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik and M.M: Yes, sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `std:wstring`, provided by the STL, as the type for your vector's elements. You can use the constructor that class provides to implicitly **copy** the contents of your `wchar_t*`-pointed buffer to the vector (in the `push_back()` call).

Here's a short demo:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t test[][8] = { L"first", L"second", L"third", L"fourth" };
    std::vector<std::wstring> vectorOfStrings;
    wchar_t* bufferForStrings;
    size_t i, length = 4;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // copy some string to the buffer...
        bufferForStrings = test[i];
        vectorOfStrings.push_back(bufferForStrings);
    }

    for (auto s : vectorOfStrings) {
        std::wcout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Further, if you later need access to the vector's elements as `wchar_t*` pointers, you can use each element's `c_str()` member function to retrieve such a pointer (though that will be `const` qualified).

There are other methods, if you want to avoid using the `std::wstring` class; for 'ordinary' `char*` buffers, you could use the [`strdup()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) to create a copy of the current buffer, and send that to `push_back()`. Unfortunately, the equivalent `wcsdup()` function is not (yet) part of the standard library (though [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strdup-wcsdup?view=msvc-160) and [others](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcsdup.html) have implemented it).